# How to mysql_dump with datagrip without database name?

Tags: mysql, datagrip

I confused with datagrip that how to dump all of my files without database name.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: I think you're referring to this function, rather than the 'dump to file' functionality within DataGrip?: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html Using DataGrip vs. another IDE/client shouldn't have any bearing on the output of this function.